# Not sent (data extract) vs bounce data view

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, subscriber-key, data-extract, bounce-management

For a specific email name, a subkey did not receive the email. I started to investigate and i saw that the subkey was in the not sent table (data extract) => field Reason equals to "Held".
WHat i don't understand is that i can not find this subkey for this specific email name in the bounce table.
An email not sent for a held reason on the email address, is it not supposed to be in the bounce table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- "Held" is a quasi-permanent status to a recipient on All Subscribers (by that I mean: you could still technically manipulate it, but it doesn't "fade away".)
- "_Bounce" data view is practically a logfile with 6 months data retention. it doesn't log recipients with their statuses, it logs events.
  In other words: No-one, not even a held user is listed permanently in _Bounce. The event data DOES indeed fade away, after six months.

So a hardbounce that happened more than six months ago is the most plausible scenario how you could be a "held" recipient, who has no event listed in "_bounce".

Answer (score 0):

I am not really 100% sure on what you are asking. Can you please re-read your question and give it an edit?

But I think you are asking:
Is an Email that is Not Sent for a Held reason supposed to also be in the Bounce table (System Data View)?

When you send an email, there are 3 possible outcomes:

1. sent
2. bounced
3. not sent

**Sent** is when the tracking pixel in the SFMC email fires and confirms to SFMC that the email has landed in that users inbox

**Bounced** is when the tracking pixel in the SFMC email fires and confirms to SFMC that the email has not landed in the users inbox (for a soft or hard bounce reason)

**Not Sent** is when the tracking pixel in the SFMC email never successfully fires to confirm to SFMC that the email has not landed or has landing in the users inbox

So can the Subkey from the Email Send be in BOTH the Not Sent tracking Extract and the Bounce table?

Yes it can. This is because sometime after send, if SFMC is not certain the email has been "Sent" or "Bounced", it registers a "Not Sent" record. That will result in a record being added to the Not Sent tracking Extract. SFMC will continue to check for 3 days if the Email landed or not. If sometime within those 3 days the tracking pixel in the SFMC email fires and confirms to SFMC that the email has not landed in the users inbox another record will be added but to the Bounce table. This is how you may see the same send appear on both the Bounce table and Not Sent tracking Extract.

Comment: very clear, thank you a lot !

Comment: I am very glad to help you :D 

Please let me know if you have any other questions about this. 

Also are you able to mark my answer as correct/helpful??

Comment: "Sent is when the tracking pixel in the SFMC email fires and confirms to SFMC that the email has landed in that users inbox" are you sure about this ? because i just found, for a specific campaign, a subscriber in this data data view whereas he had a hard bounce. Is Sent rather a data view with all the attempts of sending ?

Comment: Records get added to the Sent data view when  when the tracking pixel in the SFMC email fires and confirms to SFMC that the email has landed in that users inbox. 

If the send outcome is a Hard Bounce, that record should not go into the Sent Data View. 

Are you 100% certain the Hard Bounce record has the same jobID, email address, subkey, etc as the Sent record? If so I would reach out to SF Support.

Comment: There is no positive feedback that something landed in the inbox. Records get added to the OPEN data view when when the tracking pixel in the SFMC email fires. You can simply check that by adding the pixel via content builder. Create an html block, add a code snippet and you will see "Track email opens" in the list, which resolves to: `<custom name="opencounter" type="tracking"/>` - this does not track sends, it tracks opens.